# Synchronise files between multiple server instances

Tags: server-administration

Sites that use more than one server must have some way to deal with pushing updates to all their webservers without having to individually transfer files to each server.

I am looking for a solution to managing multiple servers on multiple machines but being able to push updates to them without having to manually transfer files to each instance.

I'm not sure if this is the right place for the question but if not please link me to a better suited site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google for chef & puppet to get you started. (I am on a small phone, and it is impractical for me to look up the URL)

for a less comprehensive solution, you could use rsync..